# Dell Switch acl to only allow port 80 and 443 to vlan

Tags: switch, dell

I'm not a network administrator, just wondering if the following acl is correct? or seems like it is correct.

ACL only allow 10.0.0.0/24 to talk to 172.18.19.0/24 on port 443

configure ACL on switch

```
console> enable 
console# configure 
console(config)# access-list DMZ ip permit tcp 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 eq 443 172.18.19.0 0.0.0.255 eq 443
console(config)# access-list DMZ permit icmp any any
```

Apply ACL on VLAN

```
console(config)# interface vlan 20 
console(config-if-vlan20)# ip access-group DMZ
console(config-if-vlan20)# exit 
console(config)# exit 
console# copy running-config startup-config
```

Comment: So... what's your question? Have you tested this?

Comment: no, I didn't, I only have core switches, and no where to test, I went over the docs and wrote the above, never tested it.

Comment: You have no workstations or servers? Is this for a home lab, or an actual professional setting?

Comment: they are core switches on production network, this is not a home lab